# How to ignore layout on a particular widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got this slight problem where my widgets in my bottom nav bar come down every time a widget becomes active. That's because there's a tiny dot that I want under the icon every time the icon becomes active.

As you can see, (this screenshot is taken in the same position) the icons go higher a little bit. I've only put the dot under the settings icon to demonstrate this problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEGo4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob1sC.png)

This is my code for the bottom navigation bar widget:

```
return BottomNavigationBar(
      showSelectedLabels: false,
      showUnselectedLabels: false,
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        const BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(MaterialSymbols.home_outlined),
          activeIcon: Icon(MaterialSymbols.home_filled_outlined),
          label: 'Home',
        ),
        const BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.quiz_outlined),
          activeIcon: Icon(Icons.quiz),
          label: 'Business',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.settings_outlined),
          activeIcon: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: const [
              Icon(Icons.settings),
              Icon(
                Icons.circle,
                size: 5,
              )
            ],
          ),
          label: 'School',
        ),
      ],
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      selectedItemColor: const Color(0xff00B2FF),
      unselectedItemColor: const Color(0xff0171A1),
      elevation: 0.0,
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    );
```

I've tried multiple things like adding padding but nothing works for me here. I'm just a beginner with flutter so I'm not advanced in this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `icon` parameter in `BottomNavigationBar` can be any widget, make it a custom widget that suites your needs. You had `Icon()` as `icon` and `Column()` with two children as `activeIcon`. They had different heights, therefore your icons were jumping. Consider this Widget that replicates your active icon, but makes the "dot" underneath the icon transparent if the item is not selected:

```
class NavBarIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final Icon icon;
  final bool isActive;

  const NavBarIcon({required this.icon, required this.isActive});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      icon,
      Icon(
        Icons.circle,
        size: 5,
        color: isActive ? null : Colors.transparent,
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

and the full snippet you can run in `Dartpad`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text('Index 0'),
    Text('Index 1'),
    Text('Index 2'),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: NavBarIcon(
                isActive: _selectedIndex == 0, icon: const Icon(Icons.home)),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: NavBarIcon(
                isActive: _selectedIndex == 1,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.quiz_outlined)),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: NavBarIcon(
                isActive: _selectedIndex == 2,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.settings)),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        selectedItemColor: const Color(0xff00B2FF),
        unselectedItemColor: const Color(0xff0171A1),
        elevation: 0.0,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NavBarIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final Icon icon;
  final bool isActive;

  const NavBarIcon({required this.icon, required this.isActive});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      icon,
      Icon(
        Icons.circle,
        size: 5,
        color: isActive ? null : Colors.transparent,
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```